# Why doesn't the line of code: char *n = malloc(sizeof(int)); throw an error?

Tags: c, memory-management

In C, my understanding is that a char type is 1 byte whereas an int is 4 bytes. I was wondering why the following code does not throw an error:

`char *n = malloc(sizeof(int));`

`n` is intended to point to a piece of memory that is 1 byte but refers to a piece of memory that is 4 bytes, shouldn't this cause some type of issue?

(apologies if this is a simple question and for lack of sophistication in some of my terms).

Thanks!

Comment: `char *n` could be a pointer to a single character, or a pointer to an array of characters. In your example, `n` points to an array of 4 characters (assuming `sizeof(int)` is equal to 4).

Comment: Best way to see for your self is `printf ("sizeof(int): %zu\n", sizeof(int));`

Comment: `n` points to the first byte of the block of 4  , this is normal in C.  You can point to subobjects of an object.

Answer (score 1):

> `n` is intended to point to a piece of memory that is 1 byte

Not really, it could also point to *more* than one byte of allocated memory.

See for instance:

```
char *str;
str = malloc(100);
```

Since `sizeof(int) > sizeof(char)` you can definitely do `malloc(sizeof(int))` even if the result is intended to be used as a `char *` pointer. It's technically *not wrong*, since `sizeof` just evaluates to a size that is bigger than 1, but it's surely bad code.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't the line of code: char *n = malloc(sizeof(int)); throw an error?

Because the C programming language does not have [static type checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_type_checking) and allows writing code that is not "type-safe". The interface exposed by `malloc` returns a pointer that is just an abstract `void*` pointer that can be used in any possible way and can be freely converted to any other pointer type.

The C language allows to cast a value between any two types and there is no kind of static type checking of assignments. You are free to make any mistakes and the compiler is not obliged to report them in any way. We, C programmers, are responsible for writing proper C code that is readable, understandable, correct and, most importantly, follows the language rules so that no "undefined behavior" happens.

Answer (score 0):

Using `malloc` function we can allocate a block of memory. So, it can either point to a byte of memory or multiple bytes of memory. `char *ptr` can either point to a character variable or it can act just like `char ptr[n]`, where `n` is the size of character array.
Also keep in mind that `malloc` returns a `void pointer`, so to avoid any type of error in your program, replace your code with:-

```
ch *n = (char *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```